# getDate()+1 gives different results for different classes

Tags: google-apps-script

I am learning Google App Scripts, and this one is driving me nuts.

I am using `getDate()+1` but getting different results for two different classes.

The same operation adds a day to one day class, but for some reason adds a year and a day to another class.

```
var theDate = new Date();  // 6/7/2018
var nextDate = new Date(); // 6/7/2018

theDate.setDate(theDate.getDate()-365); this sets the date back a year 6/7/2017 

theDate.setDate(theDate.getDate()+1); // this adds a day so 6/8/2017
```

this works

```
nextDate.setDate(theDate.getDate()+1);
```

this should add another day, making it 6/9/2017, but instead it becomes 6/9/2018. Why??

```
var formattedNowDate = Utilities.formatDate(theDate, "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd");
```

shows 2017/6/8

```
var formattedNextDate = Utilities.formatDate(nextDate, "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd");
```

shows 2018/6/9.

Why?

What am I not seeing here? This is insane...

Comment: First of all, please inform yourself what the tags you are using actually stand for.

Comment: _“this should add another day”_ - and it does. You just happen to be wrong in your idea of what you are actually “adding” it _to_ …

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Can you please explain what you mean by not adding it to the right place? I suspect I am passing a reference to original class without realizing it?

Comment: `nextDate` is still `6/7/2018` at the moment when you take the current date (meaning _day_) of `theDate`, add 1 to that, and then set that as the new _day_ for `nextDate`.